# Extracting, the XML from a Soap Request Body

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, apache-camel, cxf

I have written a web-service using a combination of  CXF and Camel.
I am working on a requirement where,

I have to publish the incoming request to a topic. i.e I have to strip the SOAP envelope and just relay the XML message/payload.

Can I do this, without having to marshal this to an XML?

The webservice does validation, before relaying the message to the topic. We don't these validations to be repeated.

Just to clarify, my route is something like this

from(cxf:endpoint).processor().marshal(JacksonXMLDataFormat).to(kafka:topic)

I would like to get rid of the processor and marshaller.

What is the better way to do this

Comment: Are you marshalling *from* XML (to POJO) or *to* XML (from POJO) ?

Comment: converting from POJO to XML. I tried writing to a kafka topic without any marshalling. I saw reference of the POJO printed. The CXF framework converts incoming service into a List of POJO. The list size is always going to be one. That's why I needed a processor, to change the exchange body to the POJO. the marshaller then converts it to an XML Stream, which I write to the Kafka Topic

Comment: Did you try the various dataFormat's ? For instance I am using `?dataFormat=POJO` so the exchange has a POJO instead of a List with one element. Ref: http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/cxf.html#CXF-Thedescriptionsofthedataformats

Comment: Thanks, I was also independently trying this. Instead of POJO, I set the <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>. This gives me the CxfPayLoad as the exchange body. CxFPayLoad.getBody() gives you a DomSource. I used the CxfPayLoad.getBodySources().get(0), which returns you a StxSource, to stream, the xml. No serialization required

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XSL transformation to "cut out" the body part and get rid of the rest.

From your Camel route you simply call it with a `.to()`

```
.to("xslt:path/to/MyTransformation.xsl")
```

where `path/to/MyTransformation.xsl` is the classpath path to your XSL stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Disabled the Java deserialization by changing the message dataFormat to PAYLOAD